# mailchimp template export to mandrill issue with merge tags

Tags: html, templates, mailchimp, mandrill

I have made templates in Mailchimp and would like to export them to Mandrill, so it can be automated when a new user signs up on our website, as a Welcome email and Getting Started email.

In the Mailchimp template, I have added the `mc:edit="name"` in the html as my mandril JSON looks for the name tag to personalise. Code is below

```
<p>Hi <span mc:edit="name">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

When I Send to Mandrill and view the source code, it ignores the mc:edit tag and shows this below

```
<p>Hi <span></span></p>
```

However, when I manually change the mandrill template to include the mc:edit, the personalisation works.

Is there some setting that I need to add in Mandrill (or Mailchimp) for this to work? It is really cumbersome to modify the mandrill template all the time because as we make changes to the mailchimp template, the mc:edit gets overridden as soon as I export it.

Comment: If it helps, I've run into this problem myself and never found a great workflow. Could try a templating/automation service on top of Mandrill, like sendwithus.com or customer.io.

Answer (score 5):

In my MailChimp template I use the following format to specify merge tags (named *name* and *product*):

```
<p>Hi *|name|*!</p>
<p>Thanks for downloading *|product|*.</p>
```

You will have to authorize MailChimp to access your Mandrill account. Assuming you have already done this, you shoud send your MailChimp template to Mandrill. You do this from the Templates page: click the Down arrow on the Edit button and select 'Send to Mandrill'. You should now see your template in you Mandrill account on the Outbound -> Templates page.

Assuming that you want send a new transactional message through Mandrill using a template, then you POST the following JSON to https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json:

```
{
    "key": "***apikey***",
    "template_name": "name-of-your-template",
    "template_content": [],
    "message": {
        "subject": "Thanks for downloading",
        "from_email": "hello@yourcompany.com",
        "from_name": "yourcompany",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "john@theircompany.com",
                "name": "John",
                "type": "to"
            }
        ],
        "merge": true,
        "merge_language": "mailchimp",
        "global_merge_vars": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "content": "John"
            },
            {
                "name": "product",
                "content": "Awesome 1.0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Frank..sorry it doesnt work though..i guess i'll just try to use the workaround method for now i.e. manually editing the html template in mandrill

Comment: It is copied from working production code (except for the names, etc.). What doesn't work?

Comment: By the way, did you send your MailChimp template to Mandrill? You must do this explicitly before you can send mail based on this template. See my updated answer.

Comment: yea I sent it to mandrill and checked the mandrill template it took the <p>Hi *|name|*!</p> piece of code. However, when I sent a test email via signup, it displayed Hi *|name|*!

Comment: @ChouOne It should have been `*|name|*` not `|name|`

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is officially no. There is nothing you can do to keep the `mc:edit` regions in exported templates: https://twitter.com/mandrillapp/status/617014296820580352.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing suggests that you're nesting that `<span>` inside another editable region. Hard to say without seeing the full code. But, `mc:edit` regions ***are*** preserved when you send to Mandrill -- that's kinda the point of being able to use the MailChimp template editor and sending to Mandrill, though it's limited to certain types of editable regions.

What you have should work, presuming that the span isn't nested inside another element with an `mc:edit` declared.

But, look at this example:

```
<div mc:edit="body_text">
This is my sample body text with an 
<span mc:edit="editable_span">editable span</span>
</div>
```

The `mc:edit` on the span will **not** get sent to Mandrill, because nested `mc:edit` regions aren't permitted in the MailChimp template language; when MailChimp exports the template, the offending `mc:edit` will be stripped. However, you should see that the `mc:edit` declaration on the `<div>` element is preserved, as expected.

If you want to do inline replacement of text, it's better to use [merge tags](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582487-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-).

Comment: It would seem not everyone at Mandrill agrees with your answer: https://twitter.com/mandrillapp/status/617014296820580352

Comment: I'd recommend testing it for yourself to confirm.

Comment: Well, I can confirm both that in my case the mc:edit section is not nested inside any other (it's actually the only one in the template) and that it is not being exported to Mandrill.

Comment: Can you provide the full HTML you're using in the mc template (redact private info if needed)? I've tested this, and can't replicate the regions being stripped except in the example I posted above.